# Is it possible to change the layer visibility (eye) icons to be more readable, in Photoshop Elements 11?

Tags: icon, layers, interface-design, adobe-photoshop-elements

In previous versions of Photoshop Elements, the eye icon appeared as opened or closed to indicate a layer's visibility. In Photoshop Elements 11, the layer's visibility is only indicated by a diagonal line through the eye icon, which makes it much harder to read at a glance.

Is it possible to change, customize, or replace the eye icons, either to the previous open/closed pair, or to something else that makes the difference between visible and hidden layers more obvious?

(I asked this question [on superuser.com before](https://superuser.com/questions/525911/is-it-possible-to-change-the-layer-visibility-eye-icons-to-be-more-readable-i), but received no response there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program we call Photoshop (be it Elements, CS-Standard or CS-Pro) is a monstrous collection of code, built to run on both Windows (XP, Vista, 7 and now 8, with 32 and 64 bit flavors) and OS X (predominantly 64 bit) with some parts dating back to the days of 16 bit processors. Times change and computers advance, and Adobe has been updating their codebase and migrating to 64 bit compliant tools. Adobe has also been striving to make the user interfaces more consistent across platform and versions. I recall several "ancient" versions of programs that modified the Photoshop interface. Since Adobe created the "CS"-series, interface hacks have been frowned upon.

I am grateful for the real advances and more advanced techniques that provide more than just glitz and feature creep. One of the biggest casualties of the migration comes from the tool used to create the pallets. The new pallets require more screen real estate compared to the 32bit pallets. The new codebase has invalidated some of the third party user interface additions.

Additionally, Apple's move to Retina displays has forced Adobe to start creating yet another set of all UI elements at double resolution, taking time away from other less-pressing programming projects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Elements but Adobe has never supported customized interface icons, as far as I can remember. The only UI adjustments (aside from your *Workspace*) is the application-wide light/dark adjustment.